# Change the celery workers' code in production without task loss

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, docker-compose, celery, django-celery

I have a system that has important long-running tasks which are executed by Celery workers. Assume that we have deployed our application using k8s or docker-compose.
How can I change the celery workers' code in production without losing the tasks that they are currently executing?
In another word, I want an elegant automated way to execute all unfinished tasks with the new workers.

I’m using Redis 4.3.3 as the broker and my Celery version is 5.2.7.

I have added result_backend and tried following settings but Celery didn't reschedule the running tasks after I ran "docker-compose restart worker_service_name".

```
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERY_TASK_REJECT_ON_WORKER_LOST = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73235267/1011253) should provide some information about running on Kubernetes.

In addition, I would recommend adding ([doc](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-worker_prefetch_multiplier)):

```
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
```

> How many messages to prefetch at a time multiplied by the number of
> concurrent processes. The default is 4 (four messages for each
> process). The default setting is usually a good choice, however – if
> you have very long running tasks waiting in the queue and you have to
> start the workers, note that the first worker to start will receive
> four times the number of messages initially. Thus the tasks may not be
> fairly distributed to the workers.
>
> To disable prefetching, set worker_prefetch_multiplier to 1. Changing
> that setting to 0 will allow the worker to keep consuming as many
> messages as it wants.