# Celery gracefull shutdown

Tags: python, celery

I have a Python application running in a docker container. The component is responsible for some long-running tasks and I want to gracefully shut down the tasks when I do a new deployment. All subworkers are killed without signaling a safe shutdown. Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Here is the code:

```
import time

from celery import Celery
from celery.signals import worker_ready
import logging

log = logging.getLogger()

app = Celery(
    "background_tasks",
    broker="redis://localhost:6379/0",
    backend="redis://localhost:6379/0",
)


@worker_ready.connect
def at_start(sender, **kwargs):
    log.info("Worker ready")
    with sender.app.connection() as connection:
        sender.app.send_task(daily_orders_import.name, connection=connection)


@app.task(acks_late=True)
def daily_orders_import():
    for u in range(1, 100):
        import_orders_from_account.delay(u)


@app.task(bind=True, acks_late=True)
def import_orders_from_account(self, u):
    while True:
        log.info(self.request)
        log.info(f"Importing orders for account {u}")
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Whos orchestrates this docker container? Kubernetes? docker-compose? can you better define long-running tasks? what's the longest task duration?

Comment: This one might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73235267/1011253

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can approach this problem, you can either use celery's own signal import or you can use the system itself.

To use celery's own signal system you can use this code:

```py
from celery.signals import worker_shutdown

@worker_shutdown.connect
def on_worker_shutdown(**kwargs):
    # Perform cleanup tasks here, such as stopping long-running tasks gracefully
    pass
```

Or to use the system's signal system you can use this:

```py
import signal
import sys

def sigterm_handler(signum, frame):
    # Perform cleanup tasks here
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)
```

Hope this helps!